# How do i get project files back into imovie?

Tags: imovie

my iMovie corrupted and the event went missing. i have found it in project files, but how to i get the project files back into an event?
i need the edit versions back into an event to continue editing them in iMovie

Answer (score 1):

Once you find the specific folder/file location of the project files, use the Import tool to add those files to a new event.